# Odd results setting margins in dp

Tags: android, layout

I use dp dimensions for everything in android. But today, I have come across a weird issue with margins.

I own a nexus 7 and a nexus 4 device. Their screens are very different related to dp units, but if I use for example 100dp for a view margin it looks exactly the same in both devices.

On the other hand, if I do the same with the dimensions of an image, I get the expected result, on nexus 4 the image if smaller than in nexus 7 device.

Why is this happenning?

Comment: Could you show code in your xml file?